# How to transclude inside directive by hand into 2 places?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to have access to result of `ng-repeat`, I've found that I can use `transclude` function and compile by hand. But the problem is that it don't work with 2 places and with element that have `ng-repeat`. My code like like this:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '?ngModel',
    template: 'HTML'
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl, $transclude) {
        var caption = element.find('.caption');
        var dropdown = element.find('.dropdown-menu');
        $transclude(function(clone) {

            //var clone_clone = clone.addClass('ng-hide');
            //$compile(clone.contents())(scope.$new()).appendTo(caption);

            $compile(clone)(scope.$new()).appendTo(dropdown);
            $compile(clone)(scope.$new()).appendTo(caption);
        });
    }
};
```

it work when I run only one compile but throw exception on the second, I've try to `clone()` also use `contents()` with `transclude: 'element'`. How can I do this? I need to have same behavior as with `ng-transclude` (`ng-translcude` don't work with `ng-repeat` because inside link I have one element instead of list of elements).

**UPDATE**: usage:

```
<dropdown>
  <li><a>foo</a></li>
  <li><a>bar</a></li>
  <li><a>baz</a></li>
</dropdown>

<dropdown>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items"><a>{{item.label}}</a></li>
</dropdown>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like and could you show the directive being used including the transcluded content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I need is to call transclude twice:

```
$transclude(function(clone) {
    $compile(clone)(scope.$new()).appendTo(caption);
});
$transclude(function(clone) {
    $compile(clone)(scope.$new()).appendTo(dropdown);
});
```